# How to look at individual test result after we adjust p value for multiple comparison

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, p-value, multiple-comparisons

For example, we have 100 biomarkers. We are making 100 t test for biomaker measures over two treatments. After p-value adjustments, we find 10 of them are significant.

Now we want to look into these 10 biomarkers. We make boxplots for these biomarkers. I want to add p values to these plots. What p values should that be? Should I use adjusted or p value from just the single t test?

Can anyone clarify me on this? I'm always a little confused on this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why not report both the unadjusted and adjusted p-values for each boxplot? The unadjusted p-value ignores the fact that you performed not only the test for a specific biomarker of the 10 you singled out, but in fact another 99 tests. The adjusted p-value takes into account the fact that you performed 100 tests in total. Both are informative in their own right. The unadjusted p-value can be misleading though as it pretends the test you performed is the only one, when in fact it is one of 100 tests.